# D3js how do I color individual parts of the map?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I wish to color the different parts of the map with different colors depending on the value that exists. The map is split into counties, and I have values for each county that I wish to translate into a color. This is my code for trying to color the map.

The range I've set is between `[ 40, 19054 ]`. It works well color the whole map one color, so for example setting color(19000) would make the whole map red.

```
     let topo = json.features
     let datas = aggCounties
    
     d3.json("/counties.json").then(function(json) {
        function getCountPerKOMKODE() {
             for (let i = 0; i < topo.length; i++) {
                  for (let j = 0; j < datas.length; j++) {
                            let jsonKOMKODE = json.features[i].properties.KOMKODE;
                            let csvKOMKODE = datas[j].kommune_kode
                            let csvCOUNT = +datas[j].count
        
                            if (csvKOMKODE == jsonKOMKODE) {
                                return csvCOUNT
                            }
                        }
                    }
        
                }
        }

        let color = d3.scaleQuantize()
                    .domain(d3.extent(getRangeDomain()))
                    .range(["white", "pink", "red"])
        
        let g = svg.append("g");
        
        g.selectAll("path").append("g")
                    .data(topo)
                    .enter()
                    .append('path')
                    .attr('class', 'county')
                    .attr("d", path)
                    .style('fill', color(getCountPerKOMKODE()))
   });
```

I feel like I'm misunderstanding the process of how the map is colored? From what I've been reading, it should target individual paths and apply the color/value given?

Thanks

**EDIT - problem solved, thanks to @AndrewReid, see code updates below:**

```
function getCountPerKOMKODE(path) {
                for (let j = 0; j < datas.length; j++) {
                   // var jsonKOMKODE = json.features[j].properties.KOMKODE;
                    let csvKOMKODE = datas[j].kommune_kode
                    let csvCOUNT = +datas[j].count

                    if (csvKOMKODE == path) {
                        return csvCOUNT
                    }
            }
        }

g.selectAll("path").append("g")
            .data(topo)
            .enter().append('path').attr('class', 'county')
            .attr("d", path).style('fill', function(d,i) {
                let komkode = d.properties.KOMKODE
                return color(getCountPerKOMKODE(komkode))
        })
```

And voila, the map is now colored.

Comment: Can you share the function `getCountPerCounty()`. If you have tweaked the name for readability in the question and it is `getCountPerKOMKODE`, a function that takes no parameters, how would a different value be retrieved every time it is called and how would that return value relate to the path you are coloring?

Comment: @AndrewReid sorry that’s a typo! Corrected it now. It takes no parameters because it check it the county codes are equal from the json and the csv file and then returns the according value from the csv file column count where that county code is matched. I hope that makes sense. So if the county code from the json is 600 then it finds the same value in the csv and returns the corresponding count.

Comment: @AndrewReid Oh you mean it should have a parameter with the path value and then check for that path value in the function? Yes I see that’s a flaw..

Comment: Currently you create a path for every item(/feature) in `topo`. You can access that bound data (the feature) with `.style('fill', function(d,i) { /* logic */ return color(value) })` where `d` is that feature (and `i` is its index) this should help you avoid the need to use a for loop with `topo`. Alternatively, you could set a property of each feature in the for loop and then access it when passing a value to color.

Comment: Oh you just made so many things click for me haha, thanks a lot, it works now. I just need to add a better color scheme to adjust for the range of values, but there is finally colors cheers!